# How to freeze a keras model and train it with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I build a model with Keras and try to freeze the Embedding layer (set Trainable=False), then I use Tensorflow to train the model. However, the Embedding layer is still trainable. The full code is as follows:

```
sen_input = Input(shape=(maxlen,), name='sen_input')
emb = Embedding(embedding.shape[0], embedding.shape[1], weights=[embedding], trainable=False, name='emb')

x = emb(sen_input)
pred = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='pred')(x)


loss = -K.sum(x * K.log(pred + K.epsilon()), axis=-1)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

Any idea to help?

Comment: How are you able to say that your embedding layer is getting trained? Can you give your full code?

Comment: I output the Embedding weights after each epoch and I find this problem. I have modified the code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly control which variables you would like to optimize and consequently which variables get trained. So, you can remove the embedding layer from that list. As you have named it as `emb`, you can write your code as (Posting only relevant parts of code)

```
var_list = [v for v in tf.all_variables() if not v.name.startswith('emb')]
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss, var_list=var_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and this is what I'm looking for. But there's another problem. Although the embedding weights are not trainable during training, I find that they are initialized randomly all over again. I think this is because of "init = tf.global_variables_initializer() sess.run(init)". Any idea to solve this problem?